# Application.rb override base Ruby class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, alias

I have a RoR application that is doing the following in its application.rb

```
Digest::MD5 = Digest::SHA256
```

This in turn ensures that everytime anyone invokes `Digest::MD5` that it will instead replace the result with a `Digest::SHA256`.  I believe this will have some unintended consequences, such as runtime issues that are hard to debug.  Is there any alternative to this approach or is this sound?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks pretty dangerous to me. I understand wanting to use SHA256 over MD5, but they're definitely not interoperable, and there are certainly benign uses for MD5 which may be used by some of your dependencies.

Instead, why not use an around alias to issue a warning if MD5 is used?

```
class Digest::MD5
   alias :orig_hexencode :hexencode

  def hexencode(str)
    Rails.logger.warn("Hexencode called #{}")
    puts caller

    orig_hexencode(str)
  end
end
```

Comment: so while the warning does help, what if MD5 were blocked at the OS level and would therefore generate an error any time it was called therefore stopping the application?

Comment: I don't think Digest::MD5 can be blocked at the OS level can it? The implementation should be specific to Ruby, not the OS.

Comment: It can, if you enforce FIPS

Comment: That's true, but would you want to? I believe some parts of the asset pipeline and ActionView digest hashes use `Digest::MD5`. If it's practical to do so, you can set `OpenSSL.fips_mode = false`, which should be the default.

Comment: right, this is specifically for the case where FIPS is required.